# Converting C# BitConverter.GetBytes() to PHP

Tags: c#, php, type-conversion

I'm trying to port this C# code to PHP:

```
var headerList = new List<byte>();

headerList.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello\n"));
headerList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(1));

byte[] header = headerList.ToArray();
```

If I output `header`, what does it looks like?

My progress so far:

```
    $in_raw = "Hello\n";
    
    for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($in_raw, 'ASCII'); $i++){
      $in.= ord($in_raw[$i]);
    }
    
    $k=1;
    $byteK=array(8); // should be 16? 32?...
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++){
        $byteK[$i] = (( $k >> (8 * $i)) & 0xFF); // Don't known if it is a valid PHP bitwise op
    }
    
    $in.=implode($byteK);

    print_r($in);
```

Which gives me this output: `721011081081111010000000`

I'm pretty confident that the first part of converting the string to ASCII bytes is correct, but these BitConverter... I don't know what to expect as output...

This string (or byte array) is used as an handshake for an socket connection. I know that the C# version does work, but my refurnished code doesn't.

Comment: If it helps, there's a C# repl online that you can use to inspect the code: https://repl.it/repls/LinedPreviousDistributionsoftware

Comment: @ChrisHaas please post it as a proper answer (with the actual output,plus any comment you may want to add), since it solves my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have access to a machine/tool that can run C#, there are a couple of [REPL websites](https://repl.it/) that you can use. I've taken your code, qualified a couple of the namespaces (just for convenience), wrapped it in a `main()` method to just run once as a CLI and [put it here](https://repl.it/repls/LinedPreviousDistributionsoftware). It also includes a `for` loop that writes the contents of the array out so that you can see what is at each index.

Here's the same code for reference:

```cs
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var headerList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<byte>();

    headerList.AddRange(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello\n"));
    headerList.AddRange(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(1));

    byte[] header = headerList.ToArray();

    foreach(byte b in header){
      Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
  }
}
```

When you run this code, the following output is generated:

```
72
101
108
108
111
10
1
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello\n").ToArray()
gives byte[6] { 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 10 }

BitConverter.GetBytes((Int64)1).ToArray()
gives byte[8] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }

BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)1).ToArray()
byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }

the last one is default compiler conversion of 1.

if PHP code please try  $byteK=array(4); and $i < 4

Answer (score 0):

The string "Hello\n" is already encoded in ASCII so you have nothing to do.

`BitConverter.GetBytes()` gives the binary representation of a 32-bit integer in machine byte order, which can be done in PHP with the [`pack()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function and the `l` format.

So the PHP code is simply:

```
$in = "Hello\n";
$in .= pack('l', 1);
```